# The password supplied to the Desired State Configuration resource is not valid. The password cannot be null or empty

Tags: powershell, dsc

I have been dealing with this error for the past day, where any Powershell DSC resource that uses a PowerShell credential object fails with the following error:

> The password supplied to the Desired State Configuration resource is not valid. The password  cannot be null or empty

The configuration has been working without issues for the last 4 years. This just started to happen 1 or 2 days ago. I am using the MSFT_ServiceResource to configure a windows service.

- I have updated the version of the resources I am using ([PSDscResources](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSDscResources)).
- I have updated the certificate I use for applying the `.mof` files on the target machine

No luck so far.

Does anyone have found this issue?
Any way to resolve it?

---

**Update 1**

These are the only two recent windows updates.
Not sure if those are related.

[image]

---

**Update 2**

I can confirm that after uninstalling update [KB5014692](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/june-14-2022-kb5014692-os-build-17763-3046-62fe56c1-a8c0-40e8-a901-677ab9538bf8) I was able to get the DSC running successfully again.

Answer (score 1):

Update: The July patches fix this issue for all affected OS versions. Tested & confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing!
we were also facing the same issue and with the ARM template picking latest version of windows server image, we have no idea why was it failing all of a sudden. We are now using the earlier version of windows server image to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

the root cause of the issue regarding the DSC… Due to June updates the Microsoft.Windows.DSC.CoreConfProviders.dll was modified on this folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Windows.DSC.CoreConfProviders\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\ to a newer version.

If you want a solution before the next patch tuesday proceed like this:

In any server who wasn't patched or you uninstalled the patch already it's only a matter to grab the dll (unpatched) and replace the dll on the affected servers. NOTE: if you have Server 2016 and 2019 the dll should be from the same OS.

that's all folks